# PayPal Express not giving option for Check out as Guest, even if it is active (PayPal Paying Guest option to YES)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, paypal

I had some problems with paypal settings in Magento 1.7.0.2 The problem is this: I am using using paypal express (I have my account created and verified Paypal Company) active PayPal Paying Guest option to YES, but when a user in my shop will complete your purchase and pay with Paypal will be the option PayPal API perfect, but does not show me the option to pay without paypal account and VERIFY ALL settings in Magento Admin Panel and \\"seem to be fine. \\"Try making a new store to rule out any configuration already had my store \\"old\\", that might not let me do my Enable PayPal Guest Checkout, but still have the same problem. I look forward to your help to solve the problem, since I have no idea what else to do on my page. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all based on browser cookies.  If you cleared your browser cookies and then try again prior to logging in to any PayPal account you should see the option for Guest Checkout more prominently displayed.

If you want to force this regardless of browser cookies you can set the following parameters in your SetExpressCheckoutRequest.

SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
LANDINGPAGE=Billing

That will force the full credit card form to be displayed by default along with the option to login and pay with PayPal.

For Magento if it's not doing this for you by default you'll need to create a module to extend the core Express Checkout module so that you can add those parameters accordingly.

Comment: I deleted the cookies but same problem, also i used another pc. one more thing is that i don't have the PayPal account optional on my Business PayPal account ! any idea of that, why i don't have this option

Comment: @Andrew.. This helped me solve the problem that was hard to find in the thin docs from PayPal. Thank you.